# Hello my fellow members, I'm new to postgresql. I want to drop table partition base on max date of field reg_dt in function as below

Tags: postgresql, function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cbsadm.create_part_tbl_cpvmm(cpvmm_custi_m text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
        DECLARE
        BEGIN
            PERFORM pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid IN 
            (SELECT pid FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks pl WHERE pl.relation in 
                (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class pc  WHERE pc.relname = 'cpvmm_custi_m' AND pc.relowner in 
                        (SELECT usesysid FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usename = 'cbsadm')));
                    
            EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || cpvmm_custi_m || '_' || to_char(now()+'1day','YYYYMMDD') || ' PARTITION OF ' || cpvmm_custi_m || ' FOR VALUES FROM (''' || to_char(now()+'1day','YYYYMMDD') ||''') TO (''' || to_char(now()+'2day','YYYYMMDD') || ''')
                tablespace tbs_cbs;';
            EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE '|| cpvmm_custi_m || '_' || to_char(now()+'1day','YYYYMMDD') ||  ' ADD  CONSTRAINT ' || cpvmm_custi_m || '_' || to_char(now()+'1day','YYYYMMDD') || '_un' || ' UNIQUE (reg_dt, card_no, card_sttl_acno);';
            EXECUTE 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_'|| cpvmm_custi_m || '_' || to_char(now()+'1day','YYYYMMDD') ||  ' ON ' || cpvmm_custi_m || '_' || to_char(now()+'1day','YYYYMMDD') || ' (reg_dt, reg_seqno, cstno) tablespace tbs_cbs;';
            EXECUTE 'ANALYZE '|| cpvmm_custi_m || '_' || to_char(now()+'1day','YYYYMMDD') ||';';
            --execute 'DROP TABLE cpvmm_custi_m_' || to_char(now()+'-10day','YYYYMMDD')||' ;';
            execute 'DROP TABLE cpvmm_custi_m_' || SELECT max(reg_dt) FROM cpvmm_custi_m +'-10day','YYYYMMDD')||' ;';
        END;
    $function$
;
```

Comment: ...and your problem is? Please take the [tour], read [ask] and edit your question with an _actual_ question.  What do you observe? What do you expect?

Comment: As as side note: dynamic SQL is better generated using the `format()` function. Easier to read and more robust with identifiers that need quoting. There is also no point in ANALYZEing the table right after creating it.

Comment: @OlafKock  my problem is
1. This function is execute drop partition base on system date
execute 'DROP TABLE cpvmm_custi_m_' || to_char(now()+'-10day','YYYYMMDD')||' ;';
2. I want this function to execute drop partition base on max date of field reg_dt in table cpvmm_custi_m but I don't know how to write script in this function.